# How do I build a JSON object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently I build a JSON object by doing:

```
@users = User.all

@users.each do |user|
  @userlist << {
    :id => user.id,
    :fname => user.fname,
    :lname => user.lname,
    :photo => user.profile_pic.url(:small)
  }
end
```

My challenge is I now want to include records from the `@contacts` table that have a different set of fields than the `User` model.

I tried doing

```
@users = User.all
@contacts = current_user.contacts
@users << @contacts
```

But that did not work. What's the best way to combine two similar models into one JSON object?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
json = User.all( :include => :contacts).to_json( :include => :contacts )
```

#### Update

Sorry, let me give a more complete answer for what you're doing...

```
@users = User.all( :include => :contacts )
@userlist = @users.map do |u|
  { :id => u.id, :fname => u.fname, :lname => u.lname, :photo => u.profile_pic.url(:small), :contacts => u.contacts }
end

json = @userlist.to_json
```

#### Another Update

Ok, so just forget me - I was having a bad day and totally missed the point of your question.  You want some JSON that includes two unrelated sets of data.  All the users, **and** the contacts just for the current user.

You want to create a new hash for that then, something like this...

```
@users = User.all
@userlist = @users.map do |u|
  { :id => u.id, :fname => u.fname, :lname => u.lname, :photo => u.profile_pic.url(:small) }
end

json = { :users => @userlist, :contacts => current_user.contacts }.to_json
```

Comment: thanks but I can't tell what this does. Can you give a little desc?

Comment: Updated, sorry for the too-brief response.

Comment: Thanks but doesn't this include all the contacts in the system? Where can I add conditions for the contacts... like Contact.find(:all, :select ... :conditions. ... ) ? thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
  @userlist = @users.map do |u|
    u.attributes.merge!(:contacts=>current_user.contacts)
  end
  json = @userlist.to_json
```

Comment: An explanation of how this is an answer to the question would have been nice.