# Group JSON by data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, json

I've got the following JSON data:

```
{
  "events":
  {
      "event":
      [
          {
              "city":"Birmingham",
              "state":"AL",
              "country":"US",
              "lat":"33.5206608",
              "lng":"-86.80249",
              "status":"Delivered",
              "occured_at":"2012-04-06
14:17:00 UTC"
          },
          {
              "city":"Birmingham",
              "state":"AL",
              "country":"US",
              "lat":"33.5206608",
              "lng":"-86.80249",
              "status":"Out
For Delivery",
              "occured_at":"2012-04-06 04:44:00 UTC"
          },
          {
              "city":"Birmingham",
              "state":"AL",
              "country":"US",
              "lat":"33.5206608",
              "lng":"-86.80249",
              "status":"Arrival
Scan",
              "occured_at":"2012-04-05 19:07:00 UTC"
          },
          {
              "city":"Doraville",
              "state":"GA",
              "country":"US",
              "lat":"33.8981579",
              "lng":"-84.2832564",
              "status":"Departure
Scan",
              "occured_at":"2012-04-05 17:08:00 UTC"
          },
          {
              "city":"Doraville",
              "state":"GA",
              "country":"US",
              "lat":"33.8981579",
              "lng":"-84.2832564",
              "status":"Arrival
Scan",
              "occured_at":"2012-04-05 11:15:00 UTC"
          },
          {
              "city":"Spartanburg",
              "state":"SC",
              "country":"US",
              "lat":"34.9495672",
              "lng":"-81.9320482",
              "status":"Departure
Scan",
              "occured_at":"2012-04-05 08:42:00 UTC"
          },
          {
              "city":"Spartanburg",
              "state":"SC",
              "country":"US",
              "lat":"34.9495672",
              "lng":"-81.9320482",
              "status":"Arrival
Scan",
              "occured_at":"2012-04-05 08:21:00 UTC"
          },
          {
              "city":"Greensboro",
              "state":"NC",
              "country":"US",
              "lat":"36.0726354",
              "lng":"-79.7919754",
              "status":"Departure
Scan",
              "occured_at":"2012-04-05 04:45:00 UTC"
          },
          {
              "city":"Greensboro",
              "state":"NC",
              "country":"US",
              "lat":"36.0726354",
              "lng":"-79.7919754",
              "status":"Origin
Scan",
              "occured_at":"2012-04-05 00:11:00 UTC"
          },
          {
              "city":null,
              "state":null,
              "country":"US",
              "status":"Billing
Information Received",
              "occured_at":"2012-04-04 18:20:27 UTC"
          }
      ]
  }
}
```

What I need to do is group the data by a combination of city, state and country, but still return the data from each item.

So for instance, group by "Birmingham, AL, US" but still be able to iterate through the `status`'s of each event (ie. Delivered, Out for Delivery, Arrival Scan) with that.

Comment: The fact that this is JSON is really irrelevant, right? You can convert it to a Ruby hash using `JSON.parse`, and then just work with that (and return it to JSON in the end if you want).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The magic you want is [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
require 'json'
all = JSON.parse(DATA.read)['events']['event']
all.group_by{ |h| [h['city'],h['state'],h['country']] }.each do |loc,events|
  puts "'#{loc.join(',')}': #{events.length} event#{:s if events.length!=1}"
  print "--> "
  puts events.map{ |e| e['status'] }.join(', ')
end

#=> 'Birmingham,AL,US': 3 events
#=> --> Delivered, Out For Delivery, Arrival Scan
#=> 'Doraville,GA,US': 2 events
#=> --> Departure Scan, Arrival Scan
#=> 'Spartanburg,SC,US': 2 events
#=> --> Departure Scan, Arrival Scan
#=> 'Greensboro,NC,US': 2 events
#=> --> Departure Scan, Origin Scan
#=> ',,US': 1 event
#=> --> Billing Information Received
```

Note that, in the above, `loc` is the three-element array returned from the block evaluated by `group_by`, and `events` is an array of all items in the same group.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an associative array so that you could use a string as the key and use that to access the records that you wish to group together. For instance, all of the Birmingham events would be accessed by:

```
events.event.Birmingham[i]
```

and all of the Spartanburg records are located in the array accessed via:

```
events.event.Spartanburg[i]
```

Below is a partial JSON example of what your serialized object would look like:

```
{
"events": {
    "event": {
        "Birmingham": [
            {
                "city": "Birmingham",
                "state": "AL",
                "country": "US",
                "lat": "33.5206608",
                "lng": "-86.80249",
                "status": "Delivered",
                "occured_at": "2012-04-06 14:17:00 UTC"
            },
            {
                "city": "Birmingham",
                "state": "AL",
                "country": "US",
                "lat": "33.5206608",
                "lng": "-86.80249",
                "status": "Out For Delivery",
                "occured_at": "2012-04-06 04:44:00 UTC"
            }
        ],
        "Spartanburg": [
            {
                "city":"Spartanburg",
                "state":"SC",
                "country":"US",
                "lat":"34.9495672",
                "lng":"-81.9320482",
                "status":"Departure Scan",
                "occured_at":"2012-04-05 08:42:00 UTC"
            },
            {
                "city": "Spartanburg",
                "state": "SC",
                "country": "US",
                "lat": "34.9495672",
                "lng": "-81.9320482",
                "status": "Arrival Scan",
                "occured_at": "2012-04-05 08:21:00 UTC"
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Here is an example of how to generate JSON in Ruby. The example was taken from [JSON implementation for Ruby](http://flori.github.com/json/doc/index.html):

```
puts JSON.pretty_generate([1, 2, {"a"=>3.141}, false, true, nil, 4..10])
```

And here is the resulting JSON generated by that command:

```
[
    1,
    2,
    {
      "a": 3.141
    },
    false,
    true,
    null,
    {
      "json_class": "Range",
      "data": [
         4,
        10,
        false
      ]
    }
]
```

Here is a partial example that will show you how you can get started with the modified example from the beginning:

```
puts JSON.pretty_generate({"events"=>{"event=>{"Birmingham"=>[{"city"=>"Birmingham","state"=>"AL"},{"city"=>"Birmingham","state"=>"AL"}]},{"Spartanburg"=>[{"city"=>"Spartanburg","state"=>"GA"}]}}})
```

Comment: That looks like what I might need. How would I convert my current JSON  code to your example?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863477/how-do-i-build-a-json-object. It describes how to build a JSON object in Ruby. Without seeing your code, I cannot be more specific than that. If it helps, the `[]` symbols mean "arrays", and the JSON consists of a separate array for each city.

Comment: Also, check out this. It has examples of more complex JSON strings: http://flori.github.com/json/doc/index.html

Comment: The JSON object is straight from a third-party API. There's no ActiveRecord object, or anything like that. It's just straight up like my example code.

Comment: @Shpigford - I updated my answer with an example. It has not been tested, but it should be enough to get you started and demonstrate the concept.